# Is an app created in Qt on Mavericks executable on other osx

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, osx-mavericks

I usually use a computer on snow leopard to create apps compatible upwards but I'm on holidays at the moment and only have my macbook pro with Mavericks on it.

I need to send an app to a customer who's on snow leopard (or lion)

Is this possible? Can I create a compatible app building it on Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on building on Mac, but I believe it is/can be. If the target computer also has Qt 5, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be "Universal" binaries that would work with both Intel based Macs and with Power PC based macs... I've seen that break on my Mavericks install for some things that were built with a "Universal" binary.  It might be just a problem with that one or two programs I was running.

The default compiler for Mavericks and Qt 5 is clang64, and so it should work on any 64 bit Intel based mac.  Make sure you are using the commandline deployment tool for qt mac deployment, so that all the dylib's get included in your app package.

Hope that helps.

Comment: apparently, it does not work. it works on mavericks clients but not on lower versions. I did use the mac deploy tool